# if statement with for loop

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

I am writing a function to calculate a value of p.

The formula is `p=r*q + pa`. The `pa` value is column vector which i have got from the `ode45` function. I have to change the value of `q` w.r.t time i.e from 0 to 1 sec `q=500`, from 1 to 2 sec `q=0`.

I have written this program:

```
function [p] = fom(t,pa)
r=0.007;
tin=1;
t=0:0.01:2;

if t <=tin
    q = 600;
else t <= 2
    q = 0;
end

[t,pa]=ode45('FOM1',[t],[0])

for i=[palv]
    p=(r*q)+(i);
end

end
```

The problem is I am getting correct values after 1 sec in my output but before 1 sec where q is 0 values are not changing.
Is this if statement correct?

Comment: There is a lot of mistakes in your code. You have two inputs but you use none of them, `(t,pa)`. You define t and pa but don't use the variables. What is `palv` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following code snippet:

```
if t <=tin
    q = 600;
else t <= 2
    q = 0;
end
```

With `t <= tin`, you compare each element of vector `t` with `tin`. The result is again a vector, which contains `1` for all elements in `t`, which are smaller than `tin`, and `0` for all elements which are larger than `tin`, i.e.

```
[ 1    1    ...     1    1    0    0    ...    0 ]
```

According to the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html), `if` evaluates the following:

> An expression is true when its result is nonempty and contains only nonzero elements (logical or real numeric). Otherwise, the expression is false.

As the vector contains ones and zeros, i.e. not only nonzero elements, the this always evaluates to *false* and the `else` clause will be executed. `q` will therefore be a scalar, not a vector, which is always `0`. To get a vector `q`, which is 600 for all `t <= tin` and zero otherwise, you can use

```
q = 600*(t <= tin);
```

which creates such a vector as printed above, and multiplies it by 600.

Now, a number of comments on your code:

Regarding the `else`: in the `else`, you can't have any other conditions, so `t <= 2` will just be executed and printed to the console, but this does nothing, so you can leave that away.

You have `t` and `pa` as inputs to the function, but never use them. `t` is simply overwritten. So either leave `t` an input and don't overwrite it, or leave it away as input. Further, you can remove `pa` as input, as you calculate it using `ode45`.

I assume `for i = palv` is a typo and should be `for i = pa`.

In this for loop, by calling `p=(r*q)+(i);`, `p` gets overwritten in every iteration, i.e. the resulting `p` will be `r*q` plus the last element of  `pa`. 
You can create a vector `p` without a for loop using

```
p = r*q + pa
```

Everything together, the function becomes

```
function p = fom(t)

r=0.007;
tin=1;

q = 600 * (t <= tin);
[t,pa]=ode45('FOM1',[t],[0])
p = r*q + pa

end
```

and can be called e.g. by

```
t = 0:0.01:2
p = fom(t);
```